# SASS mixin that applies some rules when we call it

Tags: css, sass

I would like to create a SASS/LESS mixin that asks if a variable is equal to some value then apply some CSS rules.

```
@mixin myTest($myVar: $num) {
    @if ($myVar == $num) {
      /* Apply rules if $myVar is set $num - I DO NOT KNOW WHAT SHOULD BE THERE */
    } @else {
      /* Do nothing */
    }
}
```

And then I would like to use my mixin this way:

```
$num: 1;

@include myTest(1) {
    h1 {
       color: blue;
       background: red;
    }
}

@include myTest(2) {
    h1 {
       color: yellow;
       background: green;
    }
}
```

So that only the rules inside parentheses of `@include myTest(1) { ... }` are applied.

The problem is I dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You neeed to use @content inyour mixin to get every thing that was in your mixin to be pushed through

```
$num: 1;
@mixin myTest($myVar: $num) {

    @if ($myVar == $num) {
      /* Apply rules if $myVar is set $num - I DO NOT KNOW WHAT SHOULD BE THERE */
      @content; // this is how you get it in here
    } @else {
      /* Do nothing */
    }
}

@include myTest(1) {
  h1 {
    background:red;
  }
}

@include myTest(2) {
  h1 {
    background:blue;
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YEJKRm

hopes this helps

Answer (score 1):

`myTest` checks the value of `$myVar` variable and applies passed css rules via `@content` - see [documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Passing_Content_Blocks_to_a_Mixin__mixin-content).

```
@mixin myTest($myVar: $num) {
  @if ($myVar= $num) {
    @content;
  }
}

$num: 1;

@include myTest(1) {
  h1 {
    color: blue;
    background: red;
  }
}

@include myTest(2) {
  h1 {
    color: yellow;
    background: green;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I've understood your question fully, but it seems like what you need to do is move your CSS rules inside your mixin:

```
@mixin myTest($num) {
    @if $num === 1 {
       color: blue;
       background: red;
    } @else {
       color: yellow;
       background: green;
    }
}


$num: 1;
h1 {
  @include myTest($num);
}
```

Comment: Your implementation is the standard one where the rules are inside mixin's declaration. However what I want is to apply these rules in the moment when I call the mixin.